# C# MongoDB Guid Array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document that is represented using this class

```cs
public class UnitDocument
{
    [BsonConstructor]
    public UnitDocument(Guid id, string allocId, Guid[] attachments)
    {
        Id = id;
        AllocId = allocId;
        Attachments = attachments;
    }

    [BsonId, BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
    public Guid Id { get; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string AllocId { get; }
    
    [BsonElement]
    public Guid[] Attachments { get; }
}
```

When I try to use the C# driver to insert a document I get the following error:

```cs
MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: GuidSerializer cannot serialize a Guid when GuidRepresentation is Unspecified.
```

I tried setting the `GuidRepresentation` doing the following:

```cs
[BsonElement, BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
public Guid[] Attachments { get; }
```

After doing this I get

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: [BsonGuidRepresentationAttribute] can only be used when the serializer is a GuidSerializer.
```

So I thought, I will set the Serializer:

```cs
[BsonElement, BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard), BsonSerializer(typeof(GuidSerializer))]
public Guid[] Attachments { get; }
```

Which then leads to:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value type of serializer is System.Guid and does not match member type System.Guid[]. (Parameter 'serializer')
```

What am I missing here?

Also note, that I have set the following settings globally, on startup:

```cs
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;
```

An alternative that works, but I am not super keen on is this

```
[BsonElement, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
public Guid[] Attachments { get; }
```

Is there no way to store Guids in an array in MongoDB?

Comment: which version of nuget and mongodb are you using? 
your first model should work.

Comment: I am using MongoDB.Driver version 2.14.1. The version of MongoDb is MongoDB 5.0.3 Community.

Comment: Looks like adding this line on startup did the trick: `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));`

Comment: have you tried BsonSerializers, instead of the actual attribute?
`BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line to the start-up code fixed the issue.

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
```